# Missing command in an R package

Tags: r, package, bioinformatics

So to get to the point: I need to use an R package called machuruku. To get familiar with the package I used the dataset provided in the original paper (https://academic.oup.com/sysbio/article/70/5/1033/6171196). While trying to run the code for the simulation I get an error message saying that the command "machu.simulation" doesn't exist. Any of you have any idea why that's happening? Am I missing a package?

Comment: Package [`machuruku`](https://jasonleebrown.github.io/machuruku/) is not a CRAN package and is not archived on CRAN. When using non base packages please give instructions on where and how to find them.

Comment: I suspect https://github.com/wxguillo/machuruku, @Nickmofoe please confirm. However, there is no function named `machu.simulation` in its (single file) source nor exported via its `NAMESPACE`. I don't find mention of that function in the original paper you cited, it is unclear what you are trying to do. Lacking what code you tried to do this (other than a vanilla call to `machu.simulation(something, here)`), I really don't know how to help you.

Comment: Alright sorry guys i'm new here. The package is indeed the one that @r2evans linked. So if you go the original paper I linked and download the dataset, you can find the code used to generate the results. In the the file named "simulation validation'' there is an R file called code_simulation-validation.R . In the code of the R file is the command I mentioned. I searched for it but I cannot seem to find its origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the [dataset zip file](https://uc3-s3mrt1001-prd.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/5d190e0d-4482-47a7-8668-5b977b1b7a78/data?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Ddoi_10.5061_dryad.wh70rxwk0__v4.zip&response-content-type=application%2Fzip&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjENH%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLXdlc3QtMiJGMEQCICVrIlR9ozhbR13UnZqOdNRtTiBdV4a867HpNiqC9l0iAiAWZB5YlCGXT7sXZ0%2FTALe68%2FfkNFlpu8DCSUTNUYMU5SrVBAiK%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8BEAAaDDQ1MTgyNjkxNDE1NyIM55JMfDAGYYGTw6XRKqkEnZUPyDuEJIb%2B8IgKy9HKkoE5Vqp1r9nrZD%2FofxyUH%2FNjezU9gs%2BDioxN%2B8S1y%2Fi8a27KyELQJzgml53GOWC8px8xyzKYykOO%2BQj1vOfxr56Xvv7bKNnVmoXfA4cHE%2BrWLX%2FRGxuJJZe06C0ktxxhwPwibs50MqdVLusmB1NWWD4DpcQJ6s1Ja493DUU8DtHofHJ9in%2FZkvJUgbiDZHB%2F1duJaIxRUnsFdkmuB2tevxt7QXoBOznXcaQXmBWY%2B2mI6sm6jfGivejjiAQMN9R%2BQ2C1bvzl3HfFbKlozZCVlV48K7c%2FQb%2FmhB6H7o23wpP4RB7CDS9k4xv2wJOyBtuG2rNrDiSnzlsBmsY1xjn1%2FeF7xCcgEaG2F2S4Pe8EP222PM5Mx%2FlYhz92mLFF0ljVEjWdPE3c30TpJXcWPbScIp0kT3b0vRd5owKGyp3axH71HCDV7rLFtdnDovUAzeweL%2FgbaCsy38z31%2FITkadlAU7fZvZE0ANOiGuoqGJ%2Fi13mU3bj3JQwdml3ElZLqGbMnbB5cHKez51irb%2BYEbRoGp96mNkNuli3%2FLXqP0d3GDu2ccTtzVUgcJ%2FsKfSgBX2jESiwqyKLdlmQTpCH5t0aHx2t%2FrzKWiAvHOgqp%2B%2BUKUaOqKetVfITAHH0tTJxHD1KXFQ1vDH13oVOauWt62dbAnxNbONKTo4ics1HeoNB5H8NwCkqSLvrCGrodEYpIjQLI6zflDHSiLQ1STCwnuWZBjqqAbcOJbGbVDf7jsXohT7mDQHzvVSc%2FF5t1tLb3CxnkgFecylv6Ex0qWhZSQcwinPQ184phK7p3MAXbHZnTA96rTx5nq%2FzZH1Srvdf6T85tDL4vK7s5ZMq%2B%2FXjJpwjEOC99Tf%2FKeliwVITGBLmmkyVs1gvS75Q%2Fvy7U%2FJ5QwHzB1Fbkq6SpLtC976hRA8psRdlg2t9N%2B5IP6%2Byt7S8DPbOrUy06Fd9%2BHai%2FMFS&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20221002T093447Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=14400&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAWSMX3SNWUGHDRAME%2F20221002%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=63e440bb64d2262d24d295e877df893ac5bac4cc82d97b7a04d29878cb0a7ae3), dove into the second nested zip file `Guillory_and_Brown_simulation-validation.zip`, then into its file `code_simulation-validation.R`, and noticed that this source file *uses* `machu.simulation` several times before *defining* the function starting in line 519.

Suggestions:

1. Grab lines 519 through the end, save into a different file, `source` that new file, then try to run the code in the beginning of the file again.
2. Complain (not quietly?) to the authors, the fact that they think this is reproducible means they might have missed something else, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I got one quick question: What do you mean ''source''?

Comment: I mean copy the function definition in that file to a new `.R` file and then source it. It you're using the RStudio IDE, then there's a button to source/load the whole file you have open) active in the editor. If not in the IDE, then call the `source` fibrin on that new file with the function defined. Or you can just copy the definition in lines 519 (until eof) and paste it at the beginning of the same `.R` file. Either way, it must be defined before using it.